# Counting hard links to a file in Go

Tags: unix, go, stat, hardlink

According to the [man page for FileInfo](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileInfo), the following information is available when `stat()`ing a file in Go:

```
type FileInfo interface {
        Name() string       // base name of the file
        Size() int64        // length in bytes for regular files; system-dependent for others
        Mode() FileMode     // file mode bits
        ModTime() time.Time // modification time
        IsDir() bool        // abbreviation for Mode().IsDir()
        Sys() interface{}   // underlying data source (can return nil)
}
```

**How can I retrieve the number of hard links to a specific file in Go?**

UNIX (`<sys/stat.h>`) defines `st_nlink` ("reference count of hard links") as a return value from a `stat()` system call.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For example, on Linux,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    fi, err := os.Stat("filename")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    nlink := uint64(0)
    if sys := fi.Sys(); sys != nil {
        if stat, ok := sys.(*syscall.Stat_t); ok {
            nlink = uint64(stat.Nlink)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(nlink)
}
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: this the right answer. As an addition being platform specific is advisable to communicate that by giving the suffix `_unix.go` to the module i.e. `mymodule_unix.go`

Comment: @fabrizioM: That's too simplistic. See [package build](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/).